# R: iterate over columns and plot

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
  Group Feature_A Feature_B Feature_C Feature_D
1     1         0         3         2         4
2     1         5         2         2         8
3     1         9         8         6         5
4     2         5         7         8         8
5     2         2         6         8         1
6     2         3         8         6         4
7     3         1         5         3         5
8     3         1         4         3         4

df <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Feature_A = c(0L, 
5L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), Feature_B = c(3L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 
8L, 5L, 4L), Feature_C = c(2L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 3L), Feature_D = c(4L, 
8L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L)), .Names = c("Group", "Feature_A", 
"Feature_B", "Feature_C", "Feature_D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

For every `Feature` I want to generate a plot (e.g., boxplot) that would higlight difference between `Groups`.

```
# Get unique Feature and Group
Features<-unique(colnames(df[,-1]))
Group<-unique(colnames(df$Group))
```

But how can I do the rest?
Pseudo-code might look like this:

- Select `Feature` from Data
- Split Data according `Group`
- Boxplot

  ```
  for (i in 1:levels(df$Features)){  
     for (o in 1:length(Group)){
  }}
  ```

How can I achieve this? Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put py data in the long format. Then Using `ggplot2` you can do some nice things.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
## long format using Group as id 
dat.m <- melt(dat,id='Group')
## bar plot 
p1 <- ggplot(dat.m) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=Group,y=value,fill=variable),stat='identity')
## box plot 
p2 <- ggplot(dat.m) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=factor(Group),y=value,fill=variable))
## aggregate the 2 plots
grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

[image]

Comment: one second before!! =)

Comment: @agstudy Perfect solution! One question - how to can I disable white lines between different colors in a bar?

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do. I do this all the time

The code below will generate the charts using ggplot and save them as ch_Feature_A ....

you can wrap the answer in a pdf statement to send them to pdf as well

```
library(ggplot2)
df$Group <- as.factor(df$Group)
for (i in 2:dim(df)[2]) {
  ch <- ggplot(df,aes_string(x="Group",y=names(df)[i],fill="Group"))+geom_boxplot()
  assign(paste0("ch_",names(df)[i]),ch)
}
```

or even simpler, if you do not want separate charts

```
library(reshape2)
df1 <- melt(df)
ggplot(df1,aes(x=Group,y=value,fill=Group))+geom_boxplot()+facet_grid(.~variable)
```

[image]